# Proof for the formula of probability of union of n events

Tags: probability

$$P \left( \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n} E_i \right)= \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} P(E_i)- \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} P(E_i \cap E_j) + \sum_{1 \leq i < j< k \leq n}P(E_i \cap B \cap E_k) - \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}P(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \ldots \cap E_n)$$

I proved it for $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$ and $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3\cup E_4)$, but i can't generalise this formula.how do I prove it.

Comment: Why not induction method?

Comment: There are several ways to prove it and I think that the easiest is by induction. Can you do it?

Comment: i tried it but it gets too complicated so couldn't really prove it.